# Get the workspace location of files from Perforce

Tags: perforce

When I am running `p4 files ...` and `p4 dirs ...` all the returned values have paths relative to the depot root folder. Is there a command that has the same functionality as `files` and `dirs` that returns the actual workspace path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a path you can get the workspace path in a couple of different ways (that have subtle differences):

- Run `p4 where //depot/path/...` to see the view mapping for the depot path, i.e. where the client view says this depot path maps.
- Run `p4 have //depot/path/...` to see where the depot files are synced, i.e. where they are physically located on the client.  If the files are not synced this will show you nothing (even if the files are mapped), and if the files are synced but the view mapping has changed in the meantime it will show where they were synced according to the old mapping, not where they should be according to the new mapping (i.e. what `p4 where` will show you).

When you're looking at an entire directory, either of these may yield a one-to-many answer, since different subpaths within a depot directory may map to different client directories.  Since there isn't a one-to-one relationship there isn't a `p4 dirs`-style equivalent that will give you a path like `//client/dir`; everything will be at the file level or at the mapping (i.e. `//depot/dir/... -> //client/dir/...`) level.

Note that most commands (including `p4 have` and `p4 where`) will accept local paths as well as depot paths, so you can run e.g. `p4 have ...` to see all files that you've synced under the current directory (and its output will include the depot path as well as the client path).